# Subtract one each time you iterate a twig loop

Tags: php, css, twig

I have to make a list of rating stars in twig, but I do not find how to subtract one each time I iterate the loop so that it shows one less star in the list.

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    {% for input in 0..3 %}
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="stars" />
            <label>
                {% for i in 0..4 %}
                    <span></span>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if input >= 1 %} <span class="stars">and more</span>{% endif %}
            </label>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The stars are made in CSS, so I need the second loop to show one less star each time it iterates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable in your `for`-loops to keep track of the maximum amount of stars.

```
<ul>
    {% set j = 5 %}{# max amount of stars #}
    {% for input in 1..j %}{# this will be 5 all the time, because it's allready interpreted #}
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="stars" />
            <label>
                {% for i in 1..j %}
                    <span></span>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if input >= 1 %} <span class="stars">y más</span>{% endif %}
            </label>
        </li>
        {% set j = j - 1 %}{# lower the amount of stars that will be shown next iteration #}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/1u9ut9)